# Recovering an element of a free group from its projections

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, free-groups, combinatorics-on-words

Assume you have an unknown word on an alphabet with at least three letters, and you know all the words obtained by erasing each copy of some letter. Then, you can find the first letter of the original word (it is the only one satisfying the following property : it is at the beginning of every word obtained by removing a letter which is not itself). By continuing that way, you recover the whole word.
So the map from the free monoid on $n$ letters to the product of $n$ free monoid on $n-1$ letters obtained by erasing all copies of some letters is injective.

Now I'm asking the same question for free **groups**. Of course, a word in the kernel is trivial in the abelian free group (the algebraic total number of occurrences of some letter can be recovered by removing any other letter), so it is a product of commutators. Also, it is (tautologically) for every letter $l$ a product of conjugates of $l$. But is it necessarily an empty word?

Geometrically : if a loop on the disk with $n$ points removed ($n\geq 3$) is nullhomotopic each time you add one the points back, is it necessarily nullhomotopic?

I'm afraid the answer to these questions is no, but I'm failing to either find a proof, a counterexample, or a reference addressing this question. I'm also thinking maybe $n\geq 4$ or something could work with $3$ failing.

What do you folks think? Thanks for any help :)

Comment: About to fly so TL;DR: If an element $x$ of the free group on the set of generators $\{g_{0},\dots,g_{n-1}\}$ vanishes modulo any generator, then $g_{n}xg_{n}^{-1}x^{-1}$ is an element of the free group on $\{g_{0},\dots,g_{n-1},g_{n}\}$ that vanishes modulo any generator. So you can build a counterexample for each $n$ by induction.

Comment: You're clearly right. Is something known about the kernel consisting of precisely these kinds of products of commutators between a letter and a (product of commutator between a letter and...)? Or is there probably other things in there?

Comment: Identifying the free group on $\{g_{0},\dots,g_{n-1}\}$ with the obvious subgroup of $\{g_{0},\dots,g_{n-1},g_{n}\}$, it’s not hard to see that the elements of the kernel of the latter (under the relevant morphism) are characterized as alternating (possibly empty) compositions of (nontrivial) elements of the kernel of the former with (nontrivial) powers of $g_{n}$, the exponents of the latter summing to $0$. So an inductive characterization of these kernels is, while not exactly of the form you suggest, essentially along those lines.

Comment: Hint: Iterated commutators.